# Implement a share Intent

Tags: android, image, share

I have already created a share intent implementation,This works fine for a normal, but when i click a button of sharing nothing happen...any ideas

```
public class radyo extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.radyo);
sharingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    shareIt();

    }
     private void shareIt() 
     Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
       }
});
}
   @Override
     protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

Comment: The code you posted shouldn't compile. `shareIt()` is missing its `{`. Then when it does run `sharingButton` is null since `findViewById()` hasn't been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to call `startActivity()`

```
 private void shareIt() {
     Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text to share");
     sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
     startActivity(sharingIntent);
    }
```

And keep in mind that if you want to actually [send something](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html), you will need to pass off extras to the Intent.

Comment: i made it but nothng changed :/

Comment: Please update your question with the *exact* code you're using. What you have up in your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to use a chooser to enable the user to select an app which performs the required operation.

```
String messageToShare = "your String";
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");

        share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                messageToShare);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,
                "your Title"));
```